# Convert different address formats to German one

Tags: converting, vb.net

I would like to find out which address format is input and convert it to the German format.
Examples:

- `5, Rue de l'exemple` is luxembourgish.
- `742 Evergreen Terrace` is American.

The German format is `street` `space` `house number` (no comma).

My solution approach is that no matter which of the three formats is present, the house number is always at the very front or at the very back.

Could you please look at my work to see if this can be done more efficiently?

```
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private streetAndHousenumber As String
    Private Enum Adressformate
        Deu
        USA
        Lux
        unknown
    End Enum
    Private Adressformat As Adressformate
    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label3.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Text = "742 Evergreen Terrace"
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then Return

        streetAndHousenumber = ""

        Dim temp_nr As Integer = 0

        If TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(",") <> -1 Then
            Dim split0 As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split({" "c, ","c})
            If Integer.TryParse(split0(0), temp_nr) Then
                Adressformat = Adressformate.Lux
                Label3.Text = "Lux"
                Lux_Address_to_German(split0)
            End If
            Return
        End If

        Dim split As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split({" "c})
        If split.Length = 1 Then
            Label3.Text = ""
            Adressformat = Adressformate.unknown
            Return
        End If

        If Integer.TryParse(split(0), temp_nr) Then
            Adressformat = Adressformate.USA
            Label3.Text = "USA"
            US_Address_to_German(split)
        ElseIf Integer.TryParse(split(split.Length - 1), temp_nr) Then
            Adressformat = Adressformate.Deu
            Label3.Text = "Deu"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub US_Address_to_German(split As String())
        For i As Integer = 1 To split.Length - 1 Step 1
            streetAndHousenumber += split(i) & " "
        Next
        streetAndHousenumber += split(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Lux_Address_to_German(split As String())
        For i As Integer = 2 To split.Length - 1 Step 1
            streetAndHousenumber += split(i) & " "
        Next
        streetAndHousenumber += split(0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What should happen for regions where properties aren't numbered (such as where I live)?

Comment: uuh, I didn't think so far. Return a warning

Comment: This seems like a weird thing to do, so I feel like I have to ask — why? It seems futile in the general case. See [Falsehoods programmers believe about addresses](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/).